# MAAS - HP Proliant Gen 8 + Smart Array B320i storage not found

Tags: raid, maas

I tried to install the HP Gen8 server with the Smart Array B320i enabled where I created an RAID 1 array. The commissioning of the node is going okay.
But with the Hardware tests I got the following error:

> Unable to run 'smartctl-validate':
>   'MAAS did not detect any storage devices during commissioning!'

If i go back to the BIOS and disable the Smart Array Controller all is going fine and the storage is been detected. But I want to run the node with RAID 1 enabled and i'm not sure if software RAID is a good option if one drive goes corrupt.

Any ideas how to enable the B320i driver in MAAS?

Answer (score 0):

this look like "windows based" raid controller. Linux can use it only as independed disk drives. Use normal software raid, instead.

Comment: The normal software raid is that save to use? What if one drive will fail? Just put it out and rebuild it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. Usually, this is not automatically like on a hardware controller. You need to initiate the rebuild. I used mdadm for software raid.